# How to send slider's new max/min values from a switch on another ViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, slider, viewcontroller, uiswitch

I want a switch to change my slider's min and max ranges.  I had it working on the same ViewController by setting up the switch as an action and calling salesPriceSlider.maximumValue, however I moved the switch to my settingsViewController and when I implement the same technique in prepareforSegue it's not passing?

```
   var newPriceMin = Float(0)
   var newPriceMax = Float(0)

  @IBAction func priceSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
   newPriceMax = 3000000
   newPriceMin = 1000000
  }

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var destViewController: FirstViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FirstViewController
    destViewController.salesPriceSliderOutletValue.maximumValue = newPriceMax
    destViewController.salesPriceSliderOutletValue.minimumValue = newPriceMin
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule it is a bad idea to try to manipulate a view controller's views from the outside. You should treat a view controller's views as private.

What you want to do is to set up properties in the other view controller for the desired maximum and minimum values, and then in your viewDidLoad method, apply those properties to your slider.

You can assign default values to the max and min settings so that they have reasonable values if you you don't change them from the outside.

You can also add didSet methods to your max and min values that would change the slider max/min values "live" if they get changed from the outside while the view controller is on-screen, although that's somewhat uncommon since in iOS a view controller usually has control when it is on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create two variables at Destination View Controller says:

```
var PriceMin: Float = 0.0
var PriceMax: Float(0) = 0.0
```

After that you need to access both these variables in the Main Controller just by initializing it!

```
let DestinationController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DestinationView") as! DestinationController

DestinationController.PriceMin = _newPriceMin
DestinationController.PriceMax = _newPriceMax
```

Now you can perform segue using any action!